# How to find formula given variable limits

Tags: calculus

To build a javascript game, I need a function where :
$$y <= x <= z\ (\text{and } y < z)$$
$$\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = 1,\ \ \lim_{x\to z}f(x) = 0$$
with $y$ and $z$ are variables limits.

I've started with  $a = 1 - (x / z)$

But I don't know how to include $y$ in that formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: $a={x-z\over y-z}$

Comment: perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x)=\frac{x-z}{y-z}$?

Comment: Beat you in nine seconds :))

Comment: perfect too, thanks :)